# Show that if $x_n ≥ -1$ for all n $\in \mathbb{N}$ and $ \lim_{n \to \infty}(x_n)=0 $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_n \geq -1$ for all n $\in \mathbb{N}$ and $ \lim_{n \to \infty}(x_n)=0 $. Show that If $p \in \mathbb{N}$, then  $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[p]{1+x_n}=1 $

Suggestion of how to do it, please.

Comment: you mention $p \in \mathbb N$ once but then do nothing with it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I already correct it

Comment: One approach is to simply note the continuity of the map $x \mapsto \sqrt[p]{x}$, which trivializes this proof.  Could you give us a bit more context?  What class is this for?  What tools do you have at your disposal?   What kind of proof are you expecting here?

Comment: this is analysis 1 and I'm starting the whole theme of the sequences and we have the sequence definition and all the basic elements of the theme, but I do not know how to approach this exercise.

Comment: sequence convergent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach. Since $x_n>-1$ and $0<1/p\leq1$, you can use [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality):
$$(1+x_n)^{1/p}\leq1+\frac{x_n}{p}$$
If $x_n\geq0$, one obtains
$$1\leq(1+x_n)^{1/p}\leq 1+x_n/p$$
On the other hand, if $-1<x_n<0$, one has
$$1-|x_n|<(1-|x_n|)^{1/p}\leq1-|x_n|/p$$ 
Consequently, one takes the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$ and obtains 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should focus on finding how large $n$ needs to be (in terms of $\epsilon$) to guarantee $|\sqrt[p]{1 + x_n} - 1| < \epsilon$. In this case, you'll need to use the fact that you can always find $n$ large enough to guarantee $|x_n| < \epsilon$.
You should be able to use the fact that $\sqrt[p]{x} - \sqrt[p]{y} \leq \sqrt[p]{x - y}$ when $x > y$ to get $|\sqrt[p]{1 + x_n} - 1| < \sqrt[p]{|x_n|}$. See [real analysis - Difference of nth roots vs nth root of difference ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1964151/464226) for the general statement and [real analysis - Prove the difference of roots is less than or ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/949866/464226) for the statement specifically with square roots (and absolute values!) and see if that works for you.

Comment: But my question is, how can I manipulate the radiation to get there?. I have not idea

Comment: I will add to my answer

Comment: and that's because

Answer (score 0):

If you can show that $f(x)=x^{1/p}$ is continuous then my proof will work:

Remember that if a function $f$ is continuous then $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=f(x_0)=f(\lim_{x\to x_0} x)$ or written in an equivalent way this is just $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) = f(x) = f(\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n)$.  But because $f(x)=x^{1/p}$ is continuous it follows from these facts that $\lim_{n\to \infty} (1+x_n)^{1/p}= (1+\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n)^{1/p} = (1+0)^{1/p}=1$